# Is it possible to design a global image classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, optimization, deep-learning

For neural networks, current approach requires optimization of hyper-parameters for a given training dataset. For individual dataset such as MNIST, CIFAR and,  IMAGENET, we can achieve a pretty descent accuracy.

However, my question is why we need to design individual classifier for each dataset. We do have transfer learning between different models trained on a given dataset. Can't we build a global classifier which can learn features from all these dataset, something which human brain does?

Answer (score 0):

When you look at what a neural network "learns" from a real world dataset, then it very closely resembles what is assumed the human brain does. 
In the below image from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901.pdf) the authors visualize what the neurons focus on in different layers. As you can see the first layer is basically looking for edges and simple linear shapes, the second layer builds more complex shapes and so on until the last layers go for complex concepts like dog faces or flowers. It turns out that for different datasets, the first few layers of a neural network perform very similar tasks. The further you move to the latter layers the more the network adapts to the specific dataset it is trained on.

Moreover, you can use the features form latter layers to discriminate images having different object classes on them, even though the network was not trained on these classes. The network just has no concept of what the object is.

So to answer your question, neural networks can learn features that can be used for different datasets.

[image: Visualizing Neural Networks]
Image from Zeiler, Matthew D., and Rob Fergus. "Visualizing and understanding convolutional networks." European conference on computer vision. Springer, Cham, 2014.